# Call another method after Spring MVC handler returns

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I have a requirement where I need to return some status/Long value from a rest controller and then execute code to send push notification.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create")
public String createTicket() throws InterruptedException {
    // code to create ticket
    return "ticket created";
    // need to call sendPushNotifiction() after I return status
}

    public void sendPushNotifiction() throws InterruptedException {
    // code to send push notification
    System.out.println("Sent push notification successfully!!");    
}
```

Can some one please tell me how to achieve this? Is it possible to use Spring AOP for this? I don't think thread will guaranteed execution of sendPushNotifiction method only after return. So what are the ways to achieve this effectively?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might be a good use case for asynchronous processing. Spring has [good support](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) for it. Precisely, you need to

1. Annotate `sendPushNotifiction` with `@Async`.
2. Annotate some configuration class with `@EnableAsync`.
3. Call `sendPushNotifiction()` before the return statement. The execution flow will not wait for `sendPushNotifiction` to finish.

If it doesn't work, try coding `sendPushNotifiction` in a separate service.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay, let me try this one.

Comment: what if the async function needs to start after returning from controller? Say, the async function just increments a number and publishes the result to a flux stream which you are returning from the controller and it finishes before you can even return?

Answer (score 1):

Create another method which first calls the `createTicket()` method and then calls the `sendPushNotifiction()`. That will do the job. This the simplest way in my humble opinion.

Comment: Thanks YoungHobbit, But in my scenario I would like to return first from the method as an acknowledgement and then execute some piece of code to process something. Can you please tell me the best way to achieve this?

Comment: @PratapA.K You can store the ACK message and return it after completing the `sendPushNotifiction()` method. Does this not possible for you?

Comment: It is possible but requirement is, I need to send ACK to different application and push notification to different application. So before sending push notification I am doing lot of complex mathematical operation which consumes considerable amount of time. So I don't want another app to keep on waiting so long just for ACK.
Hope you got me.

Comment: @PratapA.K then can you launch a thread which just sends the notification and exit. you can send the ACL immediately. I know launching a thread also take some time. What tread off we can make?

Comment: What's your thought on @Sainik Kumar Singhal: answer
postHandle() Interceptor of Spring?

Comment: @PratapA.K could be useful, I am not much into Spring stuff. If that helps, that is the way to go. :)

Comment: Thanks YoungHobbit. Yes @Sainik Kumar Singhal: answer will works for me. I have an interceptor already for /create request and I can make use of that. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

`createTicket()`is called by spring.You can't call it directly.You can use `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor`.Just call your `sendPushNotifiction()` method from `postHandle()` or `afterCompletion()` method of
your HandlerInterceptor

```
    package com.sample.interceptor;

   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

   public class NotifictionHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    //do nothing
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {

    //call your method here
    //call sendPushNotifiction()

}
```

}

And register you handler in spring-mvc context

```
    <mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="com.sample.NotifictionHandlerInterceptor" />
   </mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Kumar: Can you please provide piece of code?? Yes after completion of Rest request, I need to execute another piece of code.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with example code?

Comment: Thanks Sainik: I think this will fit my requirement. Let me try your answer once by monday before accepting

Comment: Hi @ Sainik : What if my sendPushNotification() method takes argument?
How can I pass arguments from createTicket --> sendPushNotification?

Comment: You can put these in request in createTicket method and retrieve in HandlerInterceptor

Answer (score 1):

The `HandlerInterceptor` is the solution, but the code get a little bit more complex than expected. Here's a code suggestion to make it simpler by putting the whole solution in a single class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create")
public String createTicket() throws InterruptedException {
    String ticket = "ticket created";
    result.set(ticket); // Save the ticket to be used after response
    return ticket;
}

public void sendPushNotifiction(String ticket) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Sent push notification successfully!!");
}

private static final ThreadLocal<String> result = new ThreadLocal<String>();

@Bean
public MappedInterceptor interceptor() {
    return new MappedInterceptor(Arrays.array("/create"), new HandlerInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
            // Get the saved object and clean for the next request
            String ticket = result.get();
            result.set(null);

            // Execute after response
            sendPushNotifiction(ticket);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i agree with youngHobbit solution where you can do like below wh

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create")
public String entryMethod() throws InterruptedException {
   String response = createTicket();
   sendPushNotifiction();
   return response ;
}

public String createTicket() throws InterruptedException {
    // code to create ticket
    return "ticket created";
    // need to call sendPushNotifiction() after I return status
}

    public void sendPushNotifiction() throws InterruptedException {
    // code to send push notification
    System.out.println("Sent push notification successfully!!");    
}
```

**Though another solution** can be to forward/redirect the request to another method once you are done with first one. But take the first approach if it solves your purpose as its simple,clear and readable

AOP is for basically dealing cross cutting concerns which you want to handle across application, should not be used for very specific purpose like this. Why to introduce extra complexity when

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply M Sach. But with this approach I can't send status back to the caller from createTicket. My createTicket is a rest method, so when user invokes this method I need to send Http status first and then push notification to some other users

Comment: Now, in entryMethod() first we are invoking sendPushNotifiction() and then returning response. But I would like to know whether it's possible to return first and then invoke sendPushNotifiction method.

Comment: Then go  for redirect request

Answer (score 0):

You can call like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create")
public void create(){
createTicket();
sendPushNotifiction();
}

public String createTicket() throws InterruptedException {
    // code to create ticket
    return "ticket created";
    // need to call sendPushNotifiction() after I return status
}

    public void sendPushNotifiction() throws InterruptedException {
    // code to send push notification
    System.out.println("Sent push notification successfully!!");    
}
```

Comment: The controller is not returning anything in this example. "ticket created" is lost in the abyss.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to postpone the execution of sendPushNotification() to some thread / thread pool. Before the return, use a queue to enqueue the processing, then in your thread dequeue and process.

However, you should take care to link your requests to the real caller and take care of failures, etc.

Web is full of examples. Look for java.util.concurrent examples, executors, ...